# How do you cancel an actionlib action?

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How does an actionlib client cancel an ongoing action?

The [docs](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib/DetailedDescription) clearly explain how to code an actionlib server to react to
a cancellation request and exit, but I can't find any example of how this is initiated by the client.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232556/how-do-you-cancel-an-actionlib-action?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-04-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each of the client APIs for the action clients has a cancel method. The full API documentation can be accessed through the **Code API** link on the main wiki page.

In the python action client, send_goal returns ClientGoalHandle which can be used to cancel the goal: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1action__client_1_1ActionClient.html#abcec1f2a881b3c41ea977da9812c313e

In the C++ action client, sendGoal returns a GoalHandle with a cancel method: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1ActionClient.html

On the python simple action client, there is a cancel_goal method: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1simple__action__client_1_1SimpleActionClient.html

On the C++ SimpleActionClient, there is a cancelGoal method: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionClient.html

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3